# Getting summary statistics from model using permutation values in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, permutation, summary

I am trying to obtain the summary statistics (`summary()`) for the linear model (below), which uses 1000 permutations of the original dataset to create a 1000 random dataset (large matrix).

```
random_model <- rep(NA,1000)

for (i in c(1:1000)) {
  random_data <- final_data
  random_data$weighted_degree <- rowSums(node.perm_1000[i,,],na.rm=T)
  random_model[i] <- coef(lm(weighted_degree ~ age + sex + age*sex, data=random_data))
}
```

I am not simply trying to compare the models to get an overall p-value but I want to get a t-value for each of the variables in the model that uses the random permutations as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `tidy()` from `broom` package. It returns the expected values like this (example):

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  term             estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>               <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept)         6.53      0.479     13.6  6.47e-28
2 iris$Sepal.Width   -0.223     0.155     -1.44 1.52e- 1
```

In your case, the previous output will be stored for each element in the list of the loop according to your definition:

```
library(broom)
#Data
random_model <- rep(NA,1000)
#Loop
for (i in c(1:1000)) {
  random_data <- final_data
  random_data$weighted_degree <- rowSums(node.perm_1000[i,,],na.rm=T)
  random_model[i] <- broom::tidy(lm(weighted_degree ~ age + sex + age*sex, data=random_data))
}
```

Comment: This is great. Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the results of interest (estimated coefficients and t-values) in a list.

Here is a reproducible example using 10 replications on the `mtcars` dataset which is sampled at 50% rate for each replication.

The results of interest are retrieved using the `$coefficients` attribute of the `summary()` output on the `lm` object.

```
# The data
data(mtcars)

# Define sample size of each replication
N <- nrow(mtcars)
sample_size <- floor(N/2)

# Number of replications (model fits) and initialization of the list to store the results 
set.seed(1717)
replications <- 10
random_model <- vector( "list", length=replications )
for (i in seq_along(random_model)) {
  shuffle = sample(N, sample_size)
  mtcars_shuffle = mtcars[shuffle, ]
  random_model[[i]] <- summary(lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + cyl*disp, data=mtcars_shuffle))$coefficients
}
```

For example, the model fitted for replications 1 and 10 are:

```
> random_model[[1]]
               Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 48.26285335 8.219065181  5.872061 7.573836e-05
cyl         -3.33999161 1.366231326 -2.444675 3.089262e-02
disp        -0.12941685 0.063269362 -2.045490 6.337414e-02
cyl:disp     0.01394436 0.007877833  1.770076 1.020931e-01

> random_model[[10]]
               Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 54.27312267 7.662593317  7.082866 1.277746e-05
cyl         -4.40545653 1.586392001 -2.777029 1.674235e-02
disp        -0.15330770 0.047932153 -3.198431 7.654790e-03
cyl:disp     0.01792561 0.006707396  2.672514 2.031615e-02
```